# stored procedure createparameter insert empty date

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I am using CLASSIC ASP with a stored procedure, the stored procedure has a date field that is not required.

I am trying to insert when there is no date entered on my form.

I have tried "", Null, NULL, vbNull.

edit: I am setting DOB to "" in the function call for this:

```
DOB = ""

if DOB = "" then
    DOB = ????
End if

Set paramId = cmdStoredProc.CreateParameter("@DOB", adDBDate, adParamInput,0,DOB)
cmdStoredProc.Parameters.Append paramId
```

This with sql server 2008.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what happens when you run your code ?

Comment: Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.

Comment: I was passing in bad data on another field and not the date field, the date field worked with Null being passed in.

Comment: Do you get this specific error when you assign Null to DOB?

Comment: It seemed if I changed the data type in the SP to adDBTimeStamp the Null worked, so everything is working now. It seems sql server does not like adDate or adDBDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Null` would normally be the correct value in this scenario.

Due lack of detail in the question I will guess.

Ulitmately you have a non-nullable DOB table field being assigned this null value at heart of the SP.  That in turn is causing an error.

Comment: Even though the problem was with passing incorrect date I still sent Null to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If `DOB` is empty try to add parameter but without a value. This will affect default value of sp parameter.

```vb
If DOB = "" Then
    Set paramId = cmdStoredProc.CreateParameter("@DOB", adDBDate, adParamInput)
Else
    Set paramId = cmdStoredProc.CreateParameter("@DOB", adDBDate, adParamInput, 0, DOB)
End If

cmdStoredProc.Parameters.Append paramId
```

Comment: I still get "Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided."

Comment: A value must be specified for the parameter, not supplying one will cause this error however `Null` ought to be an acceptable value.

Comment: If the parameter is not required, must have a default value. As I said, passing parameter without a value affects default value defined in SP and this will not cause an error for an optional parameter (as far as I know?). In such cases, there are two ways I know of. This answer is the first one. The second is, using `NamedParameters` property of `ADODB.Command` object, setting it to `True` and passing parameters except optional ones. Of course NULL is acceptable for all but there may be a different default value other than NULL for the @DBO parameter?

Comment: I assume that, there is a specified default value i.e. `.. As @DBO Date = '2011/11/11' ..`. I undersand that _"the stored procedure has a date field that is not required."_

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
if DOB = "" then
    DOB = Empty
End if
```

Comment: Still get "Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided." Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DOB field is trimmed so a space character is not tripping you up.

```
If trim(DOB) = "" then ....
```

Comment: I am setting DOB to "" for testing, so I know it is "". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because SQL Server does not support the adDBDate datatype. To correct this problem, change the datatype of the @DOB parameter to adDBTimeStamp.

```
Set paramId = cmdStoredProc.CreateParameter("@DOB", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, ,DOB)
cmdStoredProc.Parameters.Append paramId
```

[http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214459/en](http://INFO:%20%22Optional%20Feature%20Not%20Implemented%22%20Error%20Message)